# WPF Storyboards in Datatemplates

Tags: c#, wpf

Can you programmatically begin a storyboard that is within a datatemplate?

Comment: Is this via a single control, say a Button/TextBox or are you referring to within a ListBox, each item?

Comment: The data template would be applied to a single control, and it would be launched programmatically from a single control. This is all theoretical at this point, just trying to figure out the capabilities.